# Прилагательное от "инталия"

Tags: прилагательные

Интальный или инталический? Как рассуждать в таких случаях, чтобы не ошибиться?

Comment: Интальная глиптика — такой вижу термин у профессионалов.

Comment: Инталийная резьба: http://www.d-c.spb.ru/archiv/19/4/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, корректны все варианты: интальная, инталийная, инталическая (резьба), ведь
.

> Для образования от существительных прилагательных **с относительным
> значением** («относящийся к...», «сделанный из...», **«свойственный
> кому-н., чему-н.»**) чаще всего используются суффиксы:
>
> -н-:  бумажный,
> водный, железный, степной;
>
> -ое-:  берёзовый, столовый;
>
> -ск-:
> геройский, жéнский, октябрьский, учительский;
> -енн-:
> государственный, количественный, общественный;
>
> -овск-: отцовский,
> мартовский ;
>
> -еск-, -ическ-, -ческ-:  дружеский, географический,
> практический.

http://polyidioms.narod.ru/index/suffiksy_imen_prilagatelnykh/0-219

Если иметь в виду, что это **заимствование на - ия**, то суффикс -ическ больше подходит:

> Суффикс -ическ- (генетически связанный с греч. -ikos, с фр. -ique):
>
> а) идеалистический, материалистический, спиритуалистический,
> артистический, коммунистический;
>
> б) от имен существительных на -ик: трагический,
> комический, исторический, практический, политический, драматический,
> скептический, паралитический и т. п.;
>
> в) от существительных на -ика:
> пропедевтический, лингвистический, евгенический, акустический,
> фонетический, графический, грамматический и т. д.;
>
> **г) от
> заимствованных слов на -ия и бессуффиксных: философический,
> географический, биологический, энергетический, гимназический,
> идиллический, гигиенический, платонический, семитический, сценический
> и т. п.**
> http://www.booksshare.net/index.php?author=vinogradov-vv&book=2001&category=lunguistics&id1=4&page=128

Но я бы написала "**в технике инталия"**, заимствованные названия техник часто употребляются как неизменяемые слова.

Comment: На мой взгляд, прилагательные, образуемые разными корректными способами, должны различаться по употреблению. **Интальный** - имеющий _косвенное_ отношение к инталиям (напр. связанный с созданием худ. предметов в этой технике материал), **инталийный** - выполненный в технике инталии (инталийный образ Богородицы, инталийная резьба - в виде инталий и т. п.). Вариант же "_инталический_", наиболее усложнённый суффиксами, вряд ли практически полезен, если не добавляет новых значений, напр. _металлический, кристаллический_ имеют неприменимый в нашем случае смысл "сделанный из" соотв. материала.